# Querying distance on 2 dimensions in a 3 dimension spatial data set

Tags: geospatial, postgis, spatial, postgresql-9.1, spatial-query

I have a case requirement where I need to find the nearest N suppliers who supply specific product types. The types in an int range of 0..1048575, which represents an hierarchy. Any supplier could have multiple points since they could supply multiple product types.

I could store the long & lat in PostGIS and the types in an indexed int array column, and query against both with a limit of N. However, I don't believe this will be efficient as I am not sure that PostgreSQL will use both indexes.

Another idea I have is to store the types in a third "vertical" dimension. This would create stacked "vertical" shape segments at the long & lat shape of each supplier. To query, I would get the nearest long & lat intersects that simply intersect the desired type on the third dimension.

Is this possible with PostGIS using say 3DM? In other words, can I have it calculate nearest neighbor using only the long and lat, but use all 3 dimensions for the intersection?